# How to point to an external javascript file with an array in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eleventy

I have this example below, where I'm using dropdowns to filter through data.  As you can see, I have the [items] hard-coded into javascript file.  I'm hoping to point to an external javascript file, and hoping someone can help me with the best way to do that:

```
data: {
selectedType: '',
selectedCountry: '',
selectedYear: '',
items: [{
    name: 'Nolan',
    type: 'mercedes, ford',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'england'
  },
  {
    name: 'Edgar',
    type: 'bmw',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'belgium'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    type: 'bmw, audi',
    year: '2019',
    country: 'england'
  },
  {
    name: 'Axel',
    type: 'mercedes',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'england'
  }
],
```

},

https://jsfiddle.net/yrbs2650/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about. You could use JSON for data. What does this have in common with markdown?

Comment: Sorry, can forget the markdown piece, that was for something down the line (trying to hook it up to a CMS)

Comment: What does your external JS file look like? Where does this code sit?

Comment: Just another file in the app.  It's super long so just want to separate it for ease of editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear around 'external' javascript file, I'm assuming you meant it will still live in the source code but in a different file.

Use an import statement in your Vue file and an export statement in your js file

**items.js**

```
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Nolan',
    type: 'mercedes, ford',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'england'
  },
  {
    name: 'Edgar',
    type: 'bmw',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'belgium'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    type: 'bmw, audi',
    year: '2019',
    country: 'england'
  },
  {
    name: 'Axel',
    type: 'mercedes',
    year: '2020',
    country: 'england'
  }
];

export default items;
```

**app.vue**

```
import items from './items.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    selectedCountry: '',
    selectedYear: '',
    items: items,
  }
  ...
```

Depending on where you put your items.js file will change the import path, if it is a neighbor to your app.vue then ./items.js will do the trick.

The JSON format is preferred for storing data like this.
[Read about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)